# C++ How to make a numbered list only as big as the number of things in my vector

Tags: c++, vector, menu

I want to make a numbered list for the contents of my vector that will shrink or increase depending on how many things are in the vector, since the user will be able to add or delete contents in the vector at will.

In this project, the user can select from a menu to edit the vector by 1. Adding a book, 2. Showing a list of all the books in the vector, and 3. Deleting a book. The function seen below is option 3, delete a book. As you can see I have set up 'y' to be the user selection that gets erased, all I need now is a way to list the books (contents of my vector bookCollection) in a numbered list for the user.

```
int delBook(vector<string> *bookCollection)
{
    int y;
    for (vector<string>::iterator bIter = bookCollection->begin(); bIter < bookCollection->end(); bIter++)
    {
        if (bookCollection->at(y+1) == *bIter)
        {
            bookCollection->erase(bIter);
        }
    }
}
```

I want the delete selection to look something like this in the console:

1. "Book One"
2. "Book Two"
3. "Book Three"
4. "Book Four"

   Enter the number of the book you want to delete: "4"

But can shrink or increase based on how many strings have been added to the vector, so next time the user selects "3. Delete a Book" it shows:

1. "Book One"
2. "Book Two"
3. "Book Three"

   Enter the number of the book you want to delete:

I'm still very new to programming so forgive me if none of this made sense, still learning the lingo.

Comment: Just curios: _`int delBook(vector<string> *bookCollection)`_ Why do you pass `bookCollection` as a pointer? Wouldn't a reference be more suitable.

Comment: What do you mean by menu? There aren't any C++ features specifically for making menus, so you need to specify what would you want the menu to be?

Comment: I'm a student and beginner so forgive my lack of knowledge. But when I reference bookCollection in the argument, the rest of the vector bookCollection's ask for a pointer type.

Comment: I mean menu more in the sense of a numbered list. So when the user selects "Delete Book" from the main menu, it gives a numbered list of all the books in the vector. I want those tied to numbers, so the user inputs the number tied to the book they want gone.

Comment: Forgive me I'm only in my second semester of Computer Science. Just want to know if it can be done.

Comment: Also the function you're looking at is what happens with the user selects "Delete Book" from the main menu, I want to add the numbered list before 'int y;' I'm just stuck on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods for displaying and processing menus.

Here is a table driven approach:

```
struct Menu_Item
{
  const char * menu_text;
  void (*processing_function)(); // Pointer to processing function
};

void Process_Hello()
{
   std::cout << "Hello\n";
}

static const Menu_Entry menu_1[] =
{
  {"Print Hello", Process_Hello},
};
const size_t menu_1_item_count = 
sizeof(menu_1) / sizeof(menu_1[0]);

void Menu_Processor(Menu_Entry const * const p_menu,
                    size_t item_count)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < item_count; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << (i + 1) << p_menu[i].menu_text << "\n";
  }
  unsigned int selection;
  std::cin >> selection;
  // Process the selection:
  (p_menu[selection - 1])();
}
```

This method is nice because you can insert or remove entries into the table without having to change the code.  It can be improved, but this one demonstrates the concept of a table driven menu system.

Comment: Thanks! A little advanced for my knowledge of syntax right now but I'm going to mess with this and learn something new today! I appreciate the help :)